# Xubuntu add Launcher that launches two applications

Tags: xubuntu, launcher, .desktop, xfce-panel

I am using Xubuntu and trying to customize my Panel with new Launchers. I want to make a launcher that will start two applications. In this case, Chrome and Minecraft (aka lazytime launcher). I've tried:

```
java -jar /usr/share/minecraft/minecraft.jar && /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable %U
```

and

```
java -jar /usr/share/minecraft/minecraft.jar; /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable %U
```

in the "Command" box. But it only launches Minecraft. If I reverse it, only Chrome. Any ideas how ot make it work?

Comment: Sorry for waiting, I posted this and then got a little busy. Thank you it works perfectly!

Comment: Glad it works, you're welcome:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the edge of being a dupe of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/725753/desktop-entry-or-other-convinent-but-safe-way-to-exec-multiple-statements/725754#725754), also on `Xubuntu`, in a `.desktop` file, you can combine the two like:

```
/bin/bash -c "java -jar /usr/share/minecraft/minecraft.jar & /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable"
```

- You *have* to use  `/bin/bash -c` to combine the two in a `.desktop` file
- If you use `&&` or `;` instead of a single `&`, the application ('s command) waits for the first application to terminate

Comment: Thank you so much!! I'm still a noob when it comes to linux but I'm understanding more and more each day!